# How do you deploy an EXE file into my Azure account?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-storage, azure-web-roles

I have an exe file which ,when called ,opens a pdf viewer... i used it in my web application and and tried to deploy it on my azure cloud as a service. every thing worked fine but when i clicked the link or button under which i called it .it gives a runtime error as "location changed or moved"...all i want to open that viewer application to run on my azure cloud.

i m sorry if i asked a wrong question at this place .but my only need is that i want to deploy that exe in working condition . i m new to the cloud environment plzzz help me ..dont mark this question as ambiguous or can not be answered.
plzz suggest me any way by which i will be able to do so .eiher cloud service or cloud website or virtual machine etc. any single word from your wise mind will help me a lot.

the code that i used to call that exe is.

```cs
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // Create An instance of the Process class responsible for starting the newly process.

        System.Diagnostics.Process process1 = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

        // Set the directory where the file resides

        process1.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Request.MapPath("~/");

        // Set the filename name of the file you want to open

        process1.StartInfo.FileName = Request.MapPath("ProjectViewer.exe");

        // Start the process
        process1.Start();
    }
```

Comment: What is the purpose of running an EXE on the server? This won't do anything for the client.

Comment: the question actually **is** vague and not in the format for StackOverflow. Probably you could explain better what exactly does this process and why you want to start it on the server. Also are you really using `Cloud Services` or `Azure Web Sites`? Also have you included the exe file in your deployment (set the `copy to output folder` property to `copy always`). Also, for web projects when you set this property, the executable will be in `~/bin/` folder and not the root web folder...

Comment: @Silverninja -yeah u r right at some extent but as i already told that i m new to the technology and also i want that i could make a web application which can use exe files as performing its task. like suppose u dont have a development environment on ur local machine . so the whole environment can be deployed as an exe on cloud without needing to recode the applications that are very complex and time consuming to develop.

Comment: @astaykov . yeah i accept that the question is not properly formated . but the thing u prompted about putting it on bin etc. i want you to plzz continue that thing further more in detail because this is exactly i want to do .and one more thing.. is my way to call the exe is correct ?

Comment: If your .exe is managed .NET code, then adding it by reference will allow you to use its classes from within the asp.net application, as a regular library would, no extra process needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So.

First you need to make sure your executable is part of your package. For this check out [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255852/starting-an-executable-file-in-an-azure-worker-role-path-problems). For your particular case of Web Role pay attention that the executable will be in `~/bin/` folder instead of `~/`.

And for the best way to start executable in Azure check [this relevant SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915870/running-native-code-on-azure).

Comment: just one more thing can u give the solution for the processor architecture mismatch. my exe file is of x86 type and the azure supports x64. some warnings occured at packaging which i m sure produce runtime error. the warnings are .

Comment: Warning 2 There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "ProjectViewer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=x86", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets 1578 5 workerrole23m